# Show that $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}$ under certain conditions

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f(x,y)$ be a real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that if $f$ is of class $C^1$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$ exists and is continuous, then $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}$ exists and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}$

Does $C^1$ means that the function $g(a,b)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}a+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}b$ is continuous?

Comment: By definition, $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is of class $C^1$ iff $f$ is continuously differentiable, i.e. iff $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist and are continuous everywhere. Thus $g$ is indeed continuous as you suggest.

Comment: Also, this is Clairaut's theorem.

Comment: $C^1$ means that partial derivatives exist and are continuous.